# KSH - Capture Script's Return Code Before Exit

Tags: ksh

In KSH how could I trap the EXIT signal and also get the exit code for the script?

The below test outputs "About to exit script with return code 0." I'd like to get it to output the 4 from the return code of the exit command instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

trapped_exit() {
 typeset rc=$1

 echo "(LOG SCRIPT EXECUTION & RETURN CODE)"

 echo "About to exit script with return code $rc."
}

trap 'APP_RC=$?; trapped_exit $APP_RC' EXIT

exit 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I reckon I can alias the exit command to my own function. In this function I'll verify the exit command was called from my process ID and not a child process by comparing to a global variable that is previously defined. If it is from my PID I'll run my cleanup code. And finally call the real exit command with the same args.